# How do I list all yanks in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to list all the yanked text in Emacs? You can do it on Textmate with <kbd>SPLAT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

**Edit:** I meant recently killed items, items that can be yanked.

Comment: Your phrasing is a little confusing. Do you want to view the kill ring (in which case Frédéric's answer will sort you out), or do you wish to only list text which has actually been yanked from the kill ring? (which would be a somewhat odd requirement to my mind, but it better fits your question).

Comment: @phils: Textmate lets you select the item to paste from your recently yanked items. I can use C-u <item no> C-x C-y to yank an item at index 2, but i want to see a list of items in the list. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Not really, sorry. Is "the list" the kill ring (which contains copied and killed text, any item of which you *can* yank but which *may not have been yanked previously*), OR is "the list" only the items which *have* been yanked previously. "Recently yanked items" is not the same thing as "recently killed items", and it's still unclear to me which of these you mean. Note that `C-y` yanks from the kill ring.

Comment: Sorry, i meant recently killed items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To my knowledge, emacs doesn't support that feature out of the box.

If you're using a Debian or Ubuntu Linux distribution, you can install the `emacs-goodies-el` package, which contains a `browse-kill-ring` feature (bound to `M-y` by default).

Alternatively, you can use the `browse-kill-ring` ELisp package available [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/browse-kill-ring.el).

See also [here](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2010/04/navigating-kill-ring.html) for a nice article about this problem and other alternate solutions.

Comment: [*This EmacsWiki page*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing)  is the best place for info about `browse-kill-ring.el` and related code.

Answer (score 13):

The list of kills (i.e., the list of things you can yank) is called [kill ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Kill-Ring.html) and stored in the variable [`kill-ring`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Internals-of-Kill-Ring.html), so you can view it (in a not very nice way) with [`C-h v kill-ring RET`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Earlier-Kills.html).

The kill ring also appears in the menu, under “Edit / Paste from kill menu”. If you use a text mode Emacs or have turned the menu bar off, you can access the menu with `M-x tmm-menubar` (bound to `` M-` ``): type `` M-` e p `` followed by the first letter of the item you want to paste (if it's a letter and it's unique, otherwise whatever character is indicated). If you don't want to paste anything, type `` M-` e p C-g ``; the kills remain in the `*Completions*` buffer. The kill texts are displayed truncated to `yank-menu-length` characters.

Comment: The information about yank-menu-length was useful because mine was set to a very low value (20) by default on my Windows Emacs installation, making the yank menu almost useless. I set it to 250 and there's still plenty of room. The unit of measurement must be something other than characters. For what it's worth, changing its value doesn't seem to take effect until Emacs is restarted.

Answer (score 3):

EmacsWiki has a satisfying [list of solutions](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing). A portable and intuitive solution uses the **built-in** popup.el to display a vertical list to choose from:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c y") '(lambda ()
                                 (interactive)
                                 (popup-menu 'yank-menu)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Icicles** you can see all of your `kill-ring`, and yank any entries in it using completion. By default, <kbd>C-y</kbd> is bound in *Icicle* mode to `icicle-yank-maybe-completing`.

That's the same as `yank`, unless you give it a negative prefix arg (e.g., <kbd>C--</kbd>).  In that case, it lets you complete against the `kill-ring`.  Completion can be prefix, apropos (substring, regexp), or fuzzy.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands

Answer (score 1):

if you use [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm), you may call the [helm-show-kill-ring](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm-ring.el) function.

Answer (score 1):

`councel-yank-pop` wors well for me
especially with the binding suggested in
http://pragmaticemacs.com/emacs/counsel-yank-pop-with-a-tweak/

```
(use-package counsel
  :bind
  (("M-y" . counsel-yank-pop)
   :map ivy-minibuffer-map
   ("M-y" . ivy-next-line)))
```